# Cannot install hashlib on Heroku Web Application

Tags: python, python-2.7, heroku, pip, hashlib

I am trying to deploy a python web application on Heroku which uses the `hashlib` module in it. I included `hashlib` in the 'requirements.txt' file (All modules mentioned in the file are installed by Heroku using `pip`)
However it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: 'frozenset' object is not callable
```

Some other answers like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/792479) use `easy_install`, which is not supported by Heroku. Others like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083381/frozenset-object-is-not-callable) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200292/python-and-hashlib-module) are not useful in this case.

What should I do if I want to import `hashlib` in Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashlib has been included in the standard library since Python 2.5. There is no need to install it, or to include it in requirements.txt.